# DISKPART SELECT PARTITION - not a valid partition

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, android

I have MicroSD card that I used to use it for my Android device. The sdcard still works without problem in my Android devices. Now, I am going to format it as NTFS in my Windows PC. I am experiencing some difficulties as bellow:

Firstly, When I insert this MicroSD into the laptop's card-reader, Windows doesn't recognize any disk (showing no disk/media for it in My Computer folder).

Secondly, in `DISKPART`, trying to select the disk's partition ends up with an error `The specified partition is not valid. Please select a valid partition.'
Also,`CLEAN`and`CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY`commands for that disk are not successful showing`CRC` error.

[image: <code>SELECT PARTITION 1</code>]

[image]

What are these errors for? So, how can I partition/format this MicroSD so that it can work both in my Windows PC and Android device.

P.S. please don't ask me to check/change the card-reader or the MicroSD adapter or such basic/straightforward advices.

Comment: You got a CRC. That is a hardware problem.

Comment: but this MicroSD works nicely in my Android device! how it can be a hardware problem ?

Comment: Are you using an adapter to insert it into your PC, and if so, have you verified that the write-protect switch is in the proper position?

Comment: YES - NO PROBLEM WITH ADAPTER

Comment: It may work with Android, but a CRC indicates an oddity in the hardware.

Comment: The whole disk is reported by `HDD Regenerators` and `Eassos PartitionGuru` with bad sectors. This is while, the sdcard is working nicely in my Android devices. Could these be just logical bad sectors but not physical and caused by a malicious Android app trying to lock or protecting it from write operation?